# What is Entry in Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC Entry?

Tags: windows-10, license

I know what Windows 10 is. I know what IoT Enterprise edition is. I know what LTSC is. But what is the meaning of "Entry"? I can see the same vendors selling "Windows 10 IoT Enterprise 2019 LTSC Entry" and "Windows 10 IoT Enterprise 2019 LTSC" as two separate items for two separate prices. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this table at this
[link](https://www.advantech.com/products/todatasheet/3BBE22E9-3B81-4BCF-A830-413AC8F64EA8?utm_source=eStore):

[image]

So basically, "entry" means the lowest-level license, with the
fewest number of options, working on the lowest-level CPUs,
so likely also the cheapest.

Comment: Thank you so much for this great find!

Answer (score -2):

Windows 10 IoT Enterprise is the full version of Windows 10 that provides enterprise manageability and security for Internet of Things solutions. Windows 10 IoT Enterprise shares all the best of the Windows ecosystem. It is a binary for Windows 10 Enterprise, so you can use the same familiar development and administration tools as your client PC and laptop. However, there are differences between the desktop version and the Internet of Things version in terms of licensing and distribution. Note that Windows 10 IoT Enterprise offers Long Service Channel (LTSC) and semi-annual Channel (SAC) options. Oems can choose the version required for their equipment.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question.